# How I can edit yaml file in python

Tags: python, file, yaml, edit

I want to edit yaml file

```
params:
  test
description: |
  bla bla bla
  bla name2
  bla bla
```

The name after params, I can change with that

```
  with open("config.yml", 'r') as ymlfile:
    cfg = yaml.load(ymlfile)

cfg['params'] = 'lolilol'

with open('config.yml', 'w') as f:
        yaml.dump(cfg, f)
```

but I want to change, the name2 inside the descirption, how I can do it, plz

Comment: Try `print`ing (or `repr`ing) `cfg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simple can replace the `name`, but it will replace all `name`'s.

```
import yaml
with open("demo.yml", 'r') as ymlfile:
    cfg = yaml.load(ymlfile)

cfg['params'] = 'lolilol'

# replace will replace all `name's` the it will found, if you want for example to 
# replace only first word you can use `replace('name', 'new_name', 1)`
cfg['description'] = cfg['description'].replace('name', 'new_name')
print(cfg)
```

**Output**

```
{'params': 'lolilol', 
 'description': 'bla bla bla
                 bla new_name
                 bla bla'}
```

**Update**

If you want to update first name2

```
search_word = 'name2'
words = cfg['description'].split()
new_word = 'NAME'

if search_word in words:
    words[words.index(search_word)] = new_word

cfg['desciption'] = words
print(cfg)
```

**Output**

```
{'params': 'lolilol', 'description': ['bla', 'bla', 'bla', 'bla', 'NAME', 'bla', 'bla', 'name2']}
```

If you want to update all name2 founded

```
search_word = 'name2'
words = cfg['description'].split()
new_word = 'NAME'

for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if word == search_word:
        words[i] = new_word

cfg['description'] = words

print(cfg['description'])
```

**Output**

```
{'params': 'lolilol', 'description': ['bla', 'bla', 'bla', 'bla', 'NAME', 'bla', 'bla', 'NAME']}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I don't think, it is the best solution, because if my description contains the word environnemnt, and my name is env, it wil be change environnement to testironnement

Comment: i update it, you can try it, if no tell me i will delete the answer